# UITableView and UICollectionView update new cells issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uistoryboard

I am trying to work with UICollectionView that is a part of the UITableViewCell.

So the issue I faced, the collection view for visible table cells works ok, but when I start scroll table and table starts create new cells that where invisible then I faces with some behaviour that duplicate first table cell. For example I have scrolled collection view in first table view cell, then I scrolled table view down, and what I see the new cell have the same state as my first cell had. You can check source here [repo](https://github.com/matrosovDev/TestUITableViewUICollectionView) and the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77uX-wUQF8U) here to understand what I am talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Have a property of UICollectionView in CustomTableViewCell.h and bind it in Main.storyboard. Let's assume declared it like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UICollectionView *collectionView;
```

In ViewController.m change cellForRowAtIndexPath method, so it reloads inside UICollectionView every time it need

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomTableViewCell"];

    [cell.collectionView reloadData];
    [cell.collectionView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectZero animated:NO];

    return cell;
}
```

Of course, you need to import `CustomTableViewCell.h` on ViewController.m file.

Comment: ok property works good even if I reload collection view it stay on the same position, and as for this behaviour no question, so as I understood I need do it manually. Like setup initial states? Also as Dave written seems prepareForUse it what I am looking for?

Comment: Your cells are dequeued, which means the same cell is just relocated when you scroll for better performance. Imagine your table view has 1000 rows, but you can just see 10 of them at the same time. Having only 10 rows on memory is enough.
So, I edited my answer with scroll to top code.

Comment: I think your and Dave answer are good. So there is just one difference if I set this by myself in delegate method or in callback that prepareForReuse. But here is one issue I think for example if you reset collection view each time so the for example for first cell with collection view that we scrolled we also reset the position, when we go back to it. In case when I will need behaviour to keep first cell with the came state but create new one with initial state. I will faced with reset issue, that will work for each new cells.

Answer (score 1):

-[UITableViewCell prepareForReuse]

Answer (score 1):

Problem with reuse identifier in UITableView cell, if you use single cell identifier in cellForRowAtIndexPath this problem will occurs

**1. Use Dynamic cell identifier for each row, like this**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CustomTableViewCell_%d",indexPath.row]];
}
```

**2.Store content offset for each collection view in array, and reset collection view content offset**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ......
    [cell.collectionView setContentOffset:scrollingPoint animated:NO];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. can I use this in storyboard?

Comment: in your example you are using CustomTableViewCell_%d and there is no problem to pass integer value programatically. but which identifier I should set in storyboard then?

Comment: Note: in -scrollViewDidScroll, check if the passed [scrollview isKindOfClass:[UICollectionView Class]], then store that scrollView.contentOffset.x in an array